# Color State List not recognized in Shape Drawable

Tags: android, colors, xml-drawable, statelistdrawable, shapedrawable

I define following drawable `my_background_drawable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:gravity="center"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_stateful" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_png_drawable" />
</layer-list>
```

And I also define following color state list resource `color_stateful.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF00ff00"/>
    <item android:color="#FFff0000"/>
</selector>
```

When I set given `my_background_drawable` as a background for some view then I cannot observe any change in color defined in `color_stateful.xml` for my shape, while the view state is actually changed (`selector_png_drawable.xml` is an indicator).

However everything is just fine when I modify my `my_background_drawable.xml` in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- This doesn't work
    <item>
        <shape android:gravity="center"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_stateful" />
        </shape>
    </item>
-->
    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:state_pressed="true">
                <shape android:gravity="center"
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#FF00ff00" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item>
                <shape android:gravity="center"
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#FFff0000" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_png_drawable"" />
</layer-list>
```

So is it true that color state information is just lost when `ColorStateList` resource is used within a `ShapeDrawable` or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A `ColorStateList` cannot be passed as an attribute for `<solid>` in an XML definition, or really any attribute of a `<shape>`.  This attribute is inflated out of the XML as a Color resource and then passed to the Drawable's `setColor()` method, which only takes a single ARGB value.

There is only one type of Drawable instance that is designed to contain and present multiple items based on state, and that is `StateListDrawable`, which is what you get when you inflate a `<selector>`.  All other Drawable instances are meant to simply be members of this collection or drawn standalone.

Note also that an inflated `<shape>` item is actually a `GradientDrawable` and not a `ShapeDrawable`.  If you check out the `inflate()` method of `GradientDrawable` [in the source](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java), you can get all the detail you could ask for on how each attribute is used.

HTH!

Comment: As of Android Lollipop, this is no longer true and the `ColorStateList` is parsed correctly.

Comment: Can confirm it works in Lollipop - was really confused why my <21 test device wasn't working properly!

Comment: The obvious (and horrendous) alternative for pre-lollipop devices is to create as many `<shape>`s as there are states, each one only differing by their `<solid>` `color` attribute, and replace the original `<shape>` drawable by a `StateListDrawable` referencing each `<shape>`. The atrocity of the thing can be slightly mitigated by using only resource references inside the `<shape>` elements (no hard-coded values), and one can also have the original `<shape>` kept in `drawable-v21` directory (to possibly fully switch to later). _blargh_

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can assign a `ColorStateList` as a solid color inside of the xml of a a `shape` -> `GradientDrawable`, but that is only a [new feature in Lollipop](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#GradientDrawable.setColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29).

[Older versions of `GradientDrawable`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#GradientDrawable.setColor%28int%29) only accept color resources.

Currently working on a compat alternative if you are interested.

Answer (score -4):

You are doing it wring .... just Replace this

```
   android:color="@color/color_stateful"
```

with

```
android:background="@color/color_stateful"
```

update:

in your program code in the my_background_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:gravity="center"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:background="@color/color_stateful" /> <!--this is the chanage i made... here-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_png_drawable" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: There is no such an attribute as `android:background` in shape drawable