# EditText background not working

Tags: android, selector

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_rounded_borders" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> I added the useless LinearLayout just to avoid initial focus on the
>   AutoCompleteTextView when the Activity is launched

**drawable/black_rounded_borders.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/selector_black_border" />


    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**color/selector_black_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>

</selector>
```

**Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    Log.d("hasFocus", autoComplete.hasFocus() + "");
    Log.d("isSelected", autoComplete.isSelected() + "");
    Log.d("isPressed", autoComplete.isPressed() + "");
    //All the above are false
}
```

> Though all the states related the blue(#FF269ff5) color are false. I
>   still get the border in blue color. Also if I change the order of
>   states in the **color/selector_black_border.xml** file, like all false
>   first and then trues, then I get the black border. Its like only the
>   first color works.

**What am I missing?**

Thank You.

Comment: have you tried to add `android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the EditText's parent (The RelativeLayout)

Comment: Yeah. That way I can avoid this extra `LinearLayout`. But the final result is same.

Comment: if you replace `<item android:state_focused="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#FF000000"/>` with  `<item android:color="#FF000000"/>` does it work?

Comment: Okay. Though the default states are below the true states, it shows black at the beginning, works till here. But never changes to blue even after focusing, typing...

Comment: did you put it as last statement?

Comment: Yeah. its at the bottom.

Comment: Try with this `selector`: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/><!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FF269ff5"/> <!-- selected -->
     <item android:color="#FF000000" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>`

Comment: @g00dy Yeah, with that I get the initial black-color but nothing changes after clicking on it and getting focus.

Comment: @user1537779 - make a quick test, put instead of `android:background="@drawable/black_rounded_borders"` the following: `android:background="@drawable/selector_black_border"` to see if this changes it, this is just a logic test and not a final solution.

Comment: Crashes saying `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: Correction `android:background="@color/selector_black_border"` ..sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not put this into a comment, because it is too big, but I found an explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169257/color-state-list-not-recognized-in-shape-drawable), which states:

A `ColorStateList` cannot be passed as an attribute for `<solid>` in an XML definition, or really any attribute of a `<shape>`.  This attribute is inflated out of the XML as a Color resource and then passed to the Drawable's `setColor()` method, which only takes a single ARGB value.

There is only one type of Drawable instance that is designed to contain and present multiple items based on state, and that is `StateListDrawable`, which is what you get when you inflate a `<selector>`.  All other Drawable instances are meant to simply be members of this collection or drawn standalone.

Note also that an inflated `<shape>` item is actually a `GradientDrawable` and not a `ShapeDrawable`.  If you check out the `inflate()` method of `GradientDrawable` [in the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169257/color-state-list-not-recognized-in-shape-drawable), you can get all the detail you could ask for on how each attribute is used.

Credits go to @Devunwired.

However, based on that, you can create different shapes (it's a rectangle each time), which has the following properties in each and every one of them. Use the code below in `drawable/black_rounded_borders.xml` and see if it's working as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item android:state_pressed="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="#FF269ff5" />

                    <corners
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_focused="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="#FF269ff5" />

                    <corners
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_selected="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="#FF269ff5" />

                    <corners
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#FF000000" />

                    <corners
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Sorry for the long post and the fact that i don't know if it's working, but I couldn't find another way of posting this.

Comment: Just made few corrections to your code. It works thanks a lot.

Comment: Wellcome :) You can edit my post with those corrections, I would even advise that ! :) Thanks

Comment: Actually I edited, don't know where it went. Will do again, accept it.