# How to change shape colors in Drawable?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-drawable

I have the following button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_Collect"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/CollectButtonShape" />
```

which looks like this:

[image]

which consists of the following background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
  <shape android:innerRadius="0dp" android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="2" android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FF27AE60" />
  </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#FF27AE60" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

How do I programmatically change the colors of the ring and inner circle (I need to do this on the the Touch  event)???

Comment: Will the second color always be the same? If so, I'd recommend creating a second drawable for the touched state.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't decided whether to keep them the same or make the inner on different on Touch. I'm leaning towards changing both when the user Touches it. Is it difficult to do programatically?

In answer to your question, the second color will not change during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: It can be. If you look through [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change+shape+color+%5Bandroid%5D), you will find some methods of doing so

Comment: see LayerDrawable documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late reply, but I figured out that you can access each layer in a LayerList using **FindDrawableByLayerId**(). Then I have access to each object and set the appropriate color!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by having different images in drawable. Consider, if you want to change the green color into black, you need to have black color circle in drawable and then try this code. This will help you..

On the button click event, use this code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v == ButtonName) {
     ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html), it serves the purpose you are after, I think.

Comment: ColorStateList cannot be used on a drawable...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169257/color-state-list-not-recognized-in-shape-drawable

Comment: your Drawable is LayerDrawable, see the docs how to access the layers