# Change text color in shape on touch of button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors

How to change color text in button when the user touches this button?

Here is my shape.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#ffcc33" 
    android:endColor="#ffcc33"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="4dp" />
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
</item>

  <item android:state_focused="true" >
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#ffcc33" 
    android:endColor="#ffcc33"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="4dp" />
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
</item>

  <item >
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#333333" 
    android:endColor="#333333"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="4dp" />
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: is the above just used for the background of your button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940825

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547245

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use color selector, something like this

***src/color/button_text.xml***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" /> 
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000000" />
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" />
 </selector>
```

Then in the button you do this

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/text"
   android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your probably going to want to do other stuff once you have pressed the button so why not just create a normal button and set its background to your shape and then in java create an onTouch event for the button

```
    Button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                // do other stuff     
                Button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                Button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```