# Android Color Selector not working on Android 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a defined Drawable Resource(res/drawable/*.xml) which contains defined Color Resources (res/color/*.xml). Color resources contains of state selector.

In Android 5+ everything works properly, Color State Selector works properly. But on Android 4 it's not working. Why this is caused ? How to fix it ?

**Layout:**

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
```

**drawable/btn_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/login_button_border"
                android:color="@color/btn_login_border" />
            <solid android:color="@color/btn_login_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="@dimen/login_button_border">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/login_button_border"
                android:color="@color/btn_login_background" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**color/btn_login_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/login_border_highlighted" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/login_border"/>
</selector>
```

**color/btn_login_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/login_button_highlighted" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/login_button"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8169581/4198824

Comment: No way to fix it? just to use StateListDrawable? that's annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of `ColorStateList` is not supported on pre-Lollipop, maybe you can reorganize shown resources like this:

**drawable/btn_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/login_button_highlighted" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/login_button"/>
</selector>
```

**drawable/btn_login_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/login_button_border"
                android:color="@color/login_border" />
            <solid android:color="@color/login_button" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="@dimen/login_button_border">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/login_button_border"
                android:color="@color/login_button" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**drawable/btn_login_highlihted.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/login_button_border"
                android:color="@color/login_border_highlighted" />
            <solid android:color="@color/login_button_highlighted" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="@dimen/login_button_border">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/login_button_border"
                android:color="@color/login_button_highlighted" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This will remove the need of using color selectors in this case.

Comment: Yeah, this is right fix for the problem. Although it make drawables more complex and hard to maintain.